# Detect MacBook trackpad two-finger tap with JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, trackpad

I wonder if there's any way to detect if the user made a two-finger tap on the MacBook trackpad with JavaScript or jQuery. In one of the projects I'm detecting right mouse click with JavaScript and using it for some actions. It actually doesn't work when you make a double finger tap on a trackpad. While in action that works as a right click, but JavaScript can't detect it like so.

Any clues?

Comment: What JavaScript event is that?

Comment: i don't think javascript has such implementation.

Comment: When running in safari/chrome - the mouse event's button value will be 2 when two fingers are tapped on the trackpad.

Comment: To clarify to anyone answering, this question is **not** about detecting a double-click, but is instead about detecting an OS X specific two-finger tap.

Comment: Touchswipe? http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/

Comment: Your best bet is looking through the `navigator` object.

Comment: @BuddhistBeast That's aimed at the iDevices (iPad, iPhone and such), it doesn't do anything useful on a MacBook's trackpad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the mouse events `button` property - [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent)

- A value of 1 would be the indicator of a left click
- A value of 2 would be the indicator of a right click.

[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bxp8M/3/)